# JavaScript Web APIs vs jQuery for DOM selection/manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What are the best practices regarding DOM traversal/selection/manipulation? If I'm targeting the same group of elements more than once to do something, should I stick to only one way of selecting them?

For example:

```
var slidesHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("slide"); //HTMLCollection
var slidesNODE = document.querySelectorAll("slide"); //NodeList
var slidesJQUERY = $(".slide"); //jQuery object
```

Right now, I'm targeting these elements when I want to call a jQuery method  and targeting them again when I want to call a NodeList method, and again when I want to call a HTMLCollection method etc.

This seems redundant, which feels like bad practice.

However, if I select group of elements once I will have to rewrite all the other methods I want to call from scratch, which seems like overkill.

Comment: Why have you ended up with such a disparate collection of methods that take jQuery objects, NodeLists and HTMLCollections?  Do you really need those different argument types?

Comment: It seems to be very dependant on the situation, i.e. there is no one definitive answer

Comment: `$(".slide")[index]` or `$(".slide").get(index)` provide access to the `DOM` object

Comment: @JamesThorpe Because I'm learning? And I'd like some feedback on best practices? Per my post, I am targeting the same elements multiple times because I want to use some method associated with that type. Except it feels redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a better approach might be to stick to one way of selecting them, the lack of flexibility might not work well for you.

You could instead just write an agnostic element getter to get the elements and return them in the format you want:

```js
var getElements = function getElements(selector, format) {
    var elements;

    if (format.toLowerCase() === "htmlcollection") {
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName(selector); //HTMLCollection
    }

    if (format.toLowerCase() === "nodelist") {
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector); //NodeList
    }

    if (format.toLowerCase() === "jquery") {
        elements = $(selector); //jQuery object
    }

    return elements;
};

...
// meanwhile, in another part of the code...

var slidesHTML = getElements("slide", "HTMLCollection");
var slidesNODE = getElements(".slide", "NodeList");
var slidesJQUERY = getElements(".slide", "jQuery");
```

Personally speaking, I find the `HTMLCollection` and `NodeList` collections to be of little value in most cases, so for projects where I'm not using jQuery (or a similar library), I just use the following:

```js
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
```

This approach allows me the flexibility (and specificity) of CSS Selector Syntax to get DOM elements and pulls them back into an `Array` of elements where it is trivial to iterate over them or perform other operations to them.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!